# Definir o local de download e o nome de cada arquivo baixado - Selenium WebDriver C #

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Estou fazendo uma automatização utilizando o Selenium com o Chrome WebDriver. A aplicação tem de fazer uma série de downloads que precisam ser salvos com nomes diferentes (Data + Tipo do relatório) e em pastas que correspondam ao tipo de relatório que estou baixando.

O problema é que só consigo definir o diretório padrão quando instancio um novo driver

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", downloadDirectory);
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("intl.accept_languages", "nl");
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking", "true");

IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"location chromeDriver", chromeOptions);


driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
```

Sendo assim, não consigo renomear o nome do arquivo e nem selecionar o diretório correspondente do arquivo que estou baixando, ficando todos com o mesmo nome e na mesma pasta.
Alguém tem alguma ideia de como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem como fazer isso.

O que você pode fazer é criar um diretório temporário e mover seus arquivos após inseridos.

```
Using system.IO;

string downloadDirectory = @"c:\temp\MyTest.txt";

//No seu caso, o diretório `downloadDirectoryFinal` é uma variável de acordo com teus relatórios.
if (relatorioId==1)
{
   string downloadDirectoryFinal = @"c:\Relatorio1\Nome1.txt";
}
else
{
   string downloadDirectoryFinal = @"c:\Relatorio2\Nome2.txt";
}

//Diretório temporário
if(File.Exists (downloadDirectory))
{
   //Mover o arquivo para a pasta correspondente ao relatório que deseja
   File.Move(downloadDirectory, downloadDirectoryFinal);
}
```